# bash: conserve tab with spaces for alignment with column

Tags: bash, multiple-columns

I am trying to display `.tsv` files aligned nicely as columns, and yet allow limiting display to the current screen width. I am able to get this done in the following way that works in general but will fail if the input contains a particular character that is used by `column`. The current solution that I am using presently works as follows:

```
bash$ cat sample.tsv | tr '\t' '@' | column -n -t -s @ | cut -c-`tput cols`
```

I tried using tab itself directly but could not make it work. And with default option for `column`, any  whitespace and not just tabs are used so it does not work for me. Would be thankful for any better alternative than the above.

PS:
A sample is shown below

```
bash:~$ cat sample.tsv
Sl      Name    Number  Status
1       W Jhon  +1 234 4454     y
2       M Walter        +2 232 453      n
3       S M Ray +1 343 453      y
bash:~$ cat sample.tsv | tr '\t' '@' | column -n -t -s @ | cut -c-`tput cols`
Sl  Name      Number       Status
1   W Jhon    +1 234 4454  y
2   M Walter  +2 232 453   n
3   S M Ray   +1 343 453   y
bash:~$ cat sample.tsv | column -n -t | cut -c-`tput cols`
Sl  Name  Number  Status
1   W     Jhon    +1      234  4454  y
2   M     Walter  +2      232  453   n
3   S     M       Ray     +1   343   453  y
bash:~$
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal input to understand your issue ?

Comment: I have now added the minimal sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set column to use tab as character to be used to delimit columns with `-s`:

`column -t -s $'\t' -n sample.tsv`

```
Sl  Name      Number       Status
1   W Jhon    +1 234 4454  y
2   M Walter  +2 232 453   n
3   S M Ray   +1 343 453   y
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried `-s '\t'` which did not work. Why does the `$` work when it is not a variable?

Comment: This Ansi-quoting https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html